# Unable to connect to AWS RDS MySQL database from Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am running into this problem when I am trying to connect to AWS RDS MySQL database.
`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'choiceconnect-database<DB_ID>.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (timed out)")`

I have made the RDS database *Yes* to all incoming connections which seems to be the solution here to my problem. Here is my configuration URI.

`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@choiceconnect-database.<DB_ID>.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/choiceconnect-database'`

In my `application.py` I am running

```
application = Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_object(Config)
CORS(application)
db.init_app(application)


... route stuff ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with application.app_context():
        db.create_all()  # Create database tables
    application.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

I have tried making the database yes to all connections and postgres. Very confused why my flask app is not able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout is certainly a connectivity issue.
If you have already opened the Security Group to allow connections from your flask app, you can check if they have connectivity between them.
Check if they are in the same subnet, if not, check if there is a route between the two subnets.
Another possibility is check if the subnet has a NACL rule blocking it.